# Map arbitrary URL to in WordPress without 404 or "Page Not Found"

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, wordpress-theming

Let's say my blog lives here...

```
/blog/
```

Let's say I have an infinite number of arbitrary URLs...

```
/blog/browse/furniture/
/blog/browse/decor/
/blog/browse/bed/
```

I would like the theme wrapper to load the browse.php template for any pages that match the /browse/ URL pattern.

I was able to make this happen, however, while the template content loads in just fine, WordPress is treating the page as a 404 page in the background. So the page title is "Page Not Found", and built-in functions such as "is_404()" are returning true. Is there any way to map these dynamic pages and have WordPress think they are valid?

Here's the code I came up with...

```
add_filter('template_include', function($template) {
  global $wp_query;
  if ($wp_query->query['category_name'] === 'browse') {
    $template = locate_template(array('browse.php'));
  }
  return $template;
}, 99);
```

By the way, this method works because my permalink structure is set to `/%category%/%postname%/` -- so currently, WordPress sees these /browse/ pages as a category and therefore, I am able to check against the "category_name" object.

Any help you can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to check out the [rewrite endpoint API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).  While your method works, it's a hack, and is far too late in the WP load sequence to work the way you want.

Comment: Nice! This appears to be what I was looking for. I'll dig more into examples and then post back once I have something. I appreciate the other solution that was presented, but this seems to be the correct way to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you just filter the template that should be displayed - so Wordpress send a 404, and you just tell him to show a different template for your 404 page for this special case.

What you need to do is to create a page in admin and associate it to your template - doesn't matter if you don't use content or title of it. You just need to attach a post/page to your template in order to make a valid rewrite rule.

You can create that page from your plugin on activation with the following (it will store the page ID as an option):

```php
function register_activation_hook() {
    if(get_option('browse_page_id') !== false) {
        $page_id = wp_insert_post(array(
            'post_title' => __('Your page title', 'plugin-domain'),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_author' => 1,
        ));
        if($page_id && ! is_wp_error($page_id)) {
            update_post_meta($page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'browse.php');
            update_option('browse_page_id', $page_id, true);
        }
    }
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'register_activation_hook');
```

You must use this in your plugin file, and deactivate/reactivate your plugin to make it trigger.

To make your template recognized by Wordpress, add the following at the top of your template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Browse
 */
?>
```

Then, in your *functions.php*, add the following in order to define a new rewrite tag to handle your category:

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%browse_category%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

And finally, add a rewrite rule that will use the page ID previously created and the rewrite tag:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    if(get_option('browse_page_id') !== false) {
        add_rewrite_rule('^browse/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id='.get_option('browse_page_id').'&browse_category=$matches[1]','top');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

To access the category parameter in your template, use the following:

```
$wp_query->query_vars['browse_category']
```

Comment: This is a great idea, however, I was really hoping to create this functionality as a plugin that required no user setup. Your solution requires the user to create a page, set the template of the page, and then hard code the PAGE_ID in PHP. Is there any way to do this in a more automated fashion?

Comment: Then skip step #1 and #2 and use `plugins_url( '/your-plugin-template.php', __FILE__ )` as a rewrite destination instead.

Comment: I was unable to get this working. It just didn't do anything.

`function custom_rewrite_rule() {
        add_rewrite_rule('^browse/([^/]*)/?', plugins_url( '/browse.php', __FILE__ ), 'top');
    }
    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);`

-- Any ideas?

Comment: Also, the suggested method of redirecting to the plugins_url() file -- if that worked, that wouldn't integrate with my theme would it? I am looking to have the file map directly with my theme just like page.php, single.php, category.php, etc.

Comment: Well, if you're working on a plugin, you want it to be independant of the theme no? This code rewrite the rule to a template file located in your plugin folder. If you really want to rewrite to a browse.php located in theme folder, you can use `content_url('themes/your_theme/browse.php')` instead - but that make your plugin dependant of the theme.

Comment: Ah, and please notice that when you add a rewrite rules you need to flush your rewrite rules by visiting the permaling page in admin.

Comment: Ah, ok, so I got it working, however, it doesn't integrate directly with the theme like my solution -- it just displays the contents of that file and that's it. I was hoping that it integrates into my theme's template hierarchy similar to the way that single.php handles posts, and page.php handles pages, and category.php handles categories. I would like browse.php to handle 'browse' pages.

Comment: Well youre probably missing the  `get_header()` and `get_footer()` call in your template. Though, if you want to use the page solution, you can add it from your plugin without any user interaction. I updated my answer to reflect this.